# Usage of Parallel also for dependant references to the underlying span/array?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.for, partitioner

Consider this hypothetical code-snippet:

```
for (slotIdx = 1; slotIdx < slotCount/2; slotIdx++)
{              
    //we always have to go 2x slotIdx, to find the value we wanna swap behind!
    int safeNextValueIdx = slotIdx * 2;
    ref Slot nextSegmentValue = ref layout[safeNextValueIdx];
    ref Slot currPadding = ref layout[slotIdx];

    //DO NOT CHANGE THE <EXECUTION-ORDER> OF THIS CODE BLOCK! IT WORKS INTENDED IN THIS ORDER!
    short shift = tmpSrc.Swap(ref currPadding, ref nextSegmentValue);
    SwapPositions(ref nextSegmentValue, ref currPadding);
    AdjustPosition(layout, shift, safeNextValueIdx , slotIdx - 1);
}
```

From your guys perspective, can I somehow make use of, and hence get the benefits of, using `Parallel` class here?

I tried already with `Parallel.For` but  it does super weird things because sadly the elements depend sort of each other and hence are being messed up by multiple threads apparently, but could the `Partitioner.Create(source)` work here sort of, so that I can somehow slice the entire operation into independent chunks, so that

```
 ref Slot nextSlot = ref layout[safeNextValueIdx];
 ref Slot current = ref layout[slotIdx];
```

always get their values from a unique range and do not overlap with the already reserved indices?

I literally hope I did formulate myself properly!

**More info:** I am doing internal swaps to that layout span (`slots[]`) and `Slot` is a struct which has some data like `{id, type, oldPos, newPos}`. Then I am using that layout to extract certain information of a very large string I get from outside, like some complex generated hash string where I have a pattern how to find certain things in it. This is a rough explanation because it's internal stuff which I cannot share.

Comment: If they do something fully different, on same data/references how do you know that parallelization could be used here?

Comment: We need to know what, exactly, `Slot` is and what `DoSomething2With` does...

Comment: I will check some solutions I may have in reportoir and if it does not lead to anything I will definitively rewrite my post here to fill the requirments needed for you to further assist me on this! thx so far tho

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? Something which can be compiled and will have input data and desired output.

Comment: Edited: I am doing internal swaps to that layout span (slots[]) and "Slot" is a struct which has some data like "{id, type, oldPos, newPos}"

Comment: Then i am using that layout to extract certain information of a very large string i get from outside, like some complex generated hash string where i have a pattern how to find certain things in it 

This is a rough explaination because its internal stuff which i cannot share, sry but its enough to understand the idea of what is needed

Answer (score 1):

You have dependencies all the way from start to end (`n` depends on `n-1`), so if you can't break this chain -- you can't parallelize anything here.

Comment: Not sure how too break this chanins, really, but something in me cant let go of the idea to sort of get the parallel to work here

Comment: @Shpendicus you can try to rework your alg to perform two passes. In first you compute changes needed to be done (parallel), then apply them (serial but no hard computing). Don't forget to measure does it really makes it faster. We do not know how you use `n-1`, so can't help anyhow.

Comment: okay will need to check how best it can be done